# Sonata Easy-Extends bundle won't install

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I am trying to set up the Sonata User Bundle. As per the [instructions](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/master/doc/reference/installation.html) I am also trying to install Sonata Easy-Extends (according to [these instructions](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/easy-extends/master/doc/reference/installation.html)).

Unfortunately, I can't get Easy-Extends installed via composer (on Win7):

```
>composer require sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle
Please provide a version constraint for the sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle requirement: dev-master
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.5.x-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-standard-edition[2.5.x-dev].
    - symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.5.x-dev requires sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle 2.0 -> no matching package found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I have tried various version constraints, including 2.0 as suggested in the instructions.

What am I missing?

TIA
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a discussion in the sonata-users Google group, I managed to install the bundle by manually adding the following to my `composer.json`:

```
...    
"sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "dev-master",
...
```

Related thread in GG can be found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonata-users/g-e0swFQOPA).